# How to write this query in codeigniter active records

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to write this query in codeigniter active records

```
        select 
        a.parent_cat_id,a.parent_cat_name, b.child_cat_id,b.child_cat_name,
        c.sub_child_cat_id,c.sub_child_cat_name
        FROM parent_categories a,child_categories b,sub_child_categories c 
        WHERE a.parent_cat_id=b.parent_cat_id AND b.child_cat_id=c.child_cat_id
```

Tried this but it Shows 0 result

```
        $this->db->select('a.parent_cat_id,a.parent_cat_name, b.child_cat_id,b.child_cat_name,c.sub_child_cat_id,c.sub_child_cat_name');
        $this->db->from('parent_categories a,child_categories b,sub_child_categories c');
        $this->db->where('a.parent_cat_id','b.parent_cat_id'); 
        $this->db->where('b.child_cat_id','c.child_cat_id'); 
        $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

when i echo the above ci query i get

```
SELECT `a`.`parent_cat_id`, `a`.`parent_cat_name`, `b`.`child_cat_id`, `b`.`child_cat_name`, `c`.`sub_child_cat_id`, `c`.`sub_child_cat_name`
FROM `parent_categories` `a`, `child_categories` `b`, `sub_child_categories` `c`
WHERE `a`.`parent_cat_id` = 'b.parent_cat_id'
AND `b`.`child_cat_id` = 'c.child_cat_id'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `$this->db->where` in your query as below-

```
$this->db->select('a.parent_cat_id,a.parent_cat_name, b.child_cat_id,b.child_cat_name,c.sub_child_cat_id,c.sub_child_cat_name');
    $this->db->from('parent_categories a,child_categories b,sub_child_categories c');
    $this->db->where("a.parent_cat_id = b.parent_cat_id"); 
    $this->db->where("b.child_cat_id = c.child_cat_id");
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Join Query For That Here is Code Snippet

```
    $this->db->select('a.parent_cat_id,a.parent_cat_name, b.child_cat_id,b.child_cat_name,c.sub_child_cat_id,c.sub_child_cat_name'); 
    $this->db->from('parent_categories a');
    $this->db->join('child_categories b', 'b.parent_cat_id = a.parent_cat_id', 'left'); 
    $this->db->join('sub_child_categories c', 'c.child_cat_id = b.child_cat_id', 'left'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res =  $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have your table structure and data to check. But, try this. It will work.

```
 $this->db->select('a.parent_cat_id,a.parent_cat_name, b.child_cat_id,b.child_cat_name,c.sub_child_cat_id,c.sub_child_cat_name');
 $this->db->from('parent_categories a,child_categories b,sub_child_categories c');
 $this->db->join('a.parent_cat_id','b.parent_cat_id'); 
 $this->db->join('b.child_cat_id','c.child_cat_id');
 $this->db->get();
```

Comment: i get error: Table 'a.parent_cat_id' doesn't exist

i have attached db structure

Comment: can you export the sql and give me?